# Optimize javascript animation

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I have a sky full of stars (at least 200 at any given time) and I want to make them twinkle. I'm using D3.js to render the stars. Currently I'm using the following code:

```
svg.select(".stars").selectAll("circle")
  .each(function() {
    var circle = d3.select(this);
    (function twinkle() {
      circle.transition()
        .duration(20 + 480 * Math.random())
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("opacity", 0.5 + 0.5 * Math.random())
        .each("end", twinkle);
    })();
  });
```

As you can see, `twinkle()` make a random opacity animation and then recall `twinkle()`. With 200 stars it doesn't go so well:

[image: CPU consumption]

How can I optimize this?

Comment: Can you share a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)/[plunker](http://plnkr.co)/[tributary](http://tributary.io) link with the setup?

Comment: Here's the code I used as base http://blockbuilder.org/pmplewa/0e36cce6c9c5edb31e18d41ad1f82c4e

Comment: I like the solution described in the article [Night sky with twinkling stars](https://www.script-tutorials.com/night-sky-with-twinkling-stars/)  which does not involve any JavaScript at all and, therefore, will not eat up your performance. It controls the twinkling by moving around semi-transparent images using CSS animations.These semi-transparent images are then from time to time masking the background starts. You may alter the effect to add more randomness by simply adjusting the masking images.

Comment: @altocumulus Unfortunately I'm using a gradient background, so this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `setInterval`:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", 400)
 .attr("height", 400);
 
var data = d3.range(200);

var circles = svg.selectAll(".circles")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("circle");
 
circles.attr("r", 1)
 .attr("cx", function(){ return Math.random()*400})
 .attr("cy", function(){ return Math.random()*400});
 
function twinkle(){
    svg.selectAll("circle").each(function(){
    var thisCircle = d3.select(this);
    thisCircle.transition()
        .duration(20 + 480 * Math.random())
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("opacity", 0.5 + 0.5 * Math.random());
    })
}

setInterval(twinkle, 500);
```

```css
svg {
 background-color: black;
}

circle {
 fill: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made a test in my computer, but it's meaningless comparing my % with yours, because we have different computers. So, you have to benchmark this using your computer to compare the difference in performance (if any)

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for the poor performance is that Chrome is trying to maintain hundreds of parallel transitions and interpolations. Since the effect you are after is not dependent on transitions, consider removing the transition and simply updating the opacity with sufficient frequency to make it look smooth. [My attempt](http://blockbuilder.org/owenr/0b36a758f34ca47ad89fb9acd1001082) is as follows:

```
var stars = svg.select(".stars").selectAll("circle");
function twinkle() {
  stars
    .filter(function() { return Math.random() < 0.1 })
    .attr('opacity', function(d,i) { return 0.7 + 0.3 * Math.random() })
  setTimeout(twinkle, 90)
}
twinkle()
```